# WOPI error: sorry you don't have permission to edit this document

Tags: office365, ms-wopi

I want implement [WOPI](https://wopi.readthedocs.io) protocol for open and edit Office document into the browser with [Office 365](https://www.office.com/):

When Microsoft send the [CheckFileInfo](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#checkfileinfo) request:

```
GET /api/wopi/files/{IDFILE}?access_token={TOKEN}&access_token_ttl=0
```

I send this is response:

```
{
    BaseFileName: 'test2.docx',
    OwnerId: 'XXXX@gmail.com',
    UserId: 'XXXX@gmail.com',
    Size: 12642,
    SHA256: null,
    Version: '0',
    SupportsDeleteFile: false,
    SupportsEcosystem: false,
    SupportsFolders: false,
    SupportsGetFileWopiSrc: false,
    SupportsGetLock: true,
    SupportsLocks: true,
    SupportsRename: false,
    SupportsUpdate: true,
    SupportsUserInfo: false
}
```

The editor shows this error

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Office Online Server.

Solution:
You need to execute `Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm` from PowerShell as an admin, and check the `EditingEnabled` property.

If it is disabled then you can enable it via `Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -EditingEnabled:$true`

Answer (score 1):

You should return these fields in the response of CheckFileInfo.
1. [SupportUpdate](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-supportsupdate) : **true** (to let WOPI Client know that your API implement the PutFile and PutRelativeFile methods to update file)
2. [UserCanWrite](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-usercanwrite) : **true** (to indicate that the use have Write permission over the file)
3. [LicenseCheckForEditIsEnabled](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-licensecheckforeditisenabled) : **true** (to route user to Microsoft Login page to verify that the user have Office 365 license)
4. [HostEditUrl](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-hostediturl) : **url_to_your_edit_page**

**NOTE:** Your user need MS Office 365 license in order to edit file on WOPI.
[image: Valid XHTML].