# Wopi host implementation unable to open visio documents

Tags: visio, ms-wopi

I'm implementing a custom WOPI host and currently is working with word, excel and power points documents. But when I try to open a visio document (vsdx extension) I'm getting the following error:

[image: WOPI error opening visio documents]

I found the following searching on the web but I was not able to solve the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/712841/is-it-visio-edit-enabled-at-office-online-cloud-fo

[WOPI error: sorry you don't have permission to edit this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135342/wopi-error-sorry-you-dont-have-permission-to-edit-this-document)

Thanks for your help.